# Change content from menu

Tags: javascript, html

I have different titles on my left menu and I want to change the text by clicking per each title, Please let me know what function should I write on javascript and which Html tags should I use.[image: My Html page]

Here is My Titles Html script:

```html
<div class="widget">
    <ul class="feature-list">
      <li><a  href="#">Транспорт на свадьбу</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Развозка персонала</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Туризм</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Ретроавтомобили</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Бизнес-поездки</a></li>
      <li><a  href="#">Экскурсии</a></li>
    </ul>                       
</div>
```

Comment: Why can't you just use normal hypertext link navigation? When clicking on "Транспорт", you navigate to `transport.html`?

Comment: @RickardElimää Well, I want to show texts on the same page by clicking on each title, if I try to do that then I should have several Html pages which will load down the speed of my website.

Comment: Well, you need to download it sooner or later. Either by using ajax/fetch (on the same page), or by adding all code to the same page, but the latter will slow down the page load. There is hardly any difference between normal navigation or fetching on a one page design IMHO. If you want the latter, use React, Vue, Angular or any other framework.

Comment: @RickardElimää How about the changing speed? while users click on different titles they will have to wait till another page get loaded.

Comment: Images and external CSS files will be cached, and text doesn't take much time to load IMHO. It's basically the same waiting time as loading (and sometimes parsing) the page with javascript.

Comment: There are so many other things that you can focus on streamlining, like only loading the images that are on the screen (lazy loading) or just optimizing the size of the images. For javascript heavy sites, you can uglify the code.

Answer (score 0):

I believe if you would like to change the tags to be changed onclick you should add the  tags **You will need to change the http request to your requested link**

```html
<div class="menu">

  <div id="nav">
          <ul>
              <li>
              <a href="http://"><font color="#000">ЛЕГКОВЫЕ АВТОМОБИЛИ</font></a>
  
              </li>
  
              <li>
              <a href="http://">ЛИМУЗИНЫ</a>
  
              </li>
  
              <li>
              <a href="http://">МИКРОАВТОБУСЫ (4-20 МЕСТ)</a>
  
              </li>
  
              <li>
              <a href="http://">АВТОБУСЫ (25-30 МЕСТ)</a>
  
              </li>
               <li>
              <a href="http://">АВТОБУСЫ (45-50 МЕСТ</a>


  
              </li>
          </ul>
      </div>
     </div>
```

Does this answer your question?